# Calculated Formula with a conditional

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to create a calculated formula that sets the column with the value of the "**Proyecto**" text column if the column "**Estado del Proyecto**" is not "**Finalizado**", and if it is, with a blank space.

Do you see anything wrong with the formula?

```
=IF(NOT([Estado del Proyecto]="Finalizado"),Proyecto," ")
```

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it. I had to use a semicolon because of the regional settings.

Comment: If you got your solution, then please mark it as accepted answer, otherwise your question will be queued in Unanswered questions list.:)